# dynamically adding check box asp.net( csharp) and retain its value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add dynamically  checkboxlist to a section of web page.
I also need to retain its value on post back. 
How this should be done?

Comment: how do you add dynamically  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add any dynamic controls in page_init if you want their values on postback.

For example:

```
void Page_Init(object Sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var oList = new CheckBoxList();
   // Populate the values in the list
   this.Controls.Add(oList);
}
```

Comment: @user1057735: I have added an example

Answer (score 1):

If you add checkboxlist dynamically  - youll have a problem on the post - since the generated html is not as the posted one - so youll need to disable page validation in the page tag.

after that - youll be able to retrieve the values in the asp.net with : Request.Form[name...]

Answer (score 0):

You should read about ASP.NET Page Life Cycle to understand ASP.NET behavior better.
In that case, you need to add dynamic controls in PreInit, if you need some additional behavior, like themes, etc. Otherwise, you can use Init Event to add dynamic controls. Anyway, Microsoft recommends to use PreInit to "Create or re-create dynamic controls.".

You can find that information and more in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Ofcourse, I'm talking about using the server-side to do this.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);

    //add checkbox here

}
```

If you need to do that in client-side, you can use a hidden field (server-side) to track the value selected in checkbox or use the request as others already told in here.