# add handler to checkbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am adding template fields in grid-view dynamically

I am adding checkbox column in following way

```
Dim checkbox As New CheckBox()
checkbox.ID = "chk" & i.ToString
AddHandler checkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf ViewDetails
checkbox.Checked = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("STORE CD").ToString()
checkbox.AutoPostBack = True
checkbox.Checked = True
e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(checkbox)
```

But function ViewDetails cant be call
please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001213/adding-an-event-handler-to-a-dynamically-created-checkbox-aspx-c

Comment: i am not getting link...please tell me how to add controls dynamically during OnInit

Comment: Please see this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614617/dynamically-adding-check-box-asp-net-csharp-and-retain-its-value-on-postback